# How can get the query result of order parent-child then paren-child in the table with parent-child relationship?

Tags: sql, database

How can I get the query result as the picute below?

Text field is random text (not by alphabet order as the picture).
[image]

Comment: Exam/assignment question? It's best to say so, if so. I recommend people here offer hints rather than direct answers.

Comment: No, this is not exam/assignment question. I draw it for easy to understand the problem.

Comment: OK. Did you also attempt to solve it yourself?

Comment: Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 1):

For the data you have presented, `order by text` works.  However, that is probably not a general solution for what you want to do, unless the names of the nodes (as in your example) follow a very set pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Order it in ascending order

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY Text ASC
```